# Issue in creating a tabbed navigation app in ios 5 with xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, tabbed-view

I am trying to change a tabbed application on **xcode 4** to incorporate a navigation controller without storyboard.
The 1st tab contains a table. This is the one that needs to be navigable.

Here is FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource> {
IBOutlet UITableView *storeDetailsTable;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *storeDetailsTable;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *resultData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *populatedStoreArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *images;


@end
```

Here's the NavController.h:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface NavController : UINavigationController

    @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController * navController;

    @end
```

So, I'm using NavController as a UIViewControllerSubclass and then changed it to the above.

The AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class NavController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NavController *navController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NavController *navController;

@end
```

And AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "NavController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;
@synthesize navController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    navController = [[NavController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavController" bundle:nil];
//        UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, viewController2, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Now when I build and run it, I see 2 tabs. But the first tab is just a blank black screen depicting the Navigation controller but there's no tableview as should be.

Is there something I have missed?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code I can't see that you're initing the FirstViewController class and making it known to the NavController. The NavController needs to init with a RootViewController, like:

```
NavController *myNavController = [[NavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourFirstViewController];
```

A good place to find more info is at: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html